# How do I save a specific array value to a cell in Excel with Python?

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to save an array value into a cell in Excel using Python, but I can work out how.

I tried all of the followings but none worked:

```
 ws['A2'] = data[0][1]
 ws['A2'] = 'data[0][1]'
 cellValue = data[0][1]
 ws['A2'] = cellValue
```

Obviously, I'm a beginner in Python! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `ws` in your code? And what didn't work?

Comment: My ws:        ws = wb.active     . I get an error and the data isn't saved to the file after I do:      wb.save("example.xlsx")

Comment: You should add such error to your question and also add the definition of ws, wb and what library you are using, otherwise it will be difficult to understand the problem. In other words you should add a [mcve]

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry! I did get it though on my own though, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard lib xlwt:

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook() #create your workbook
ws = wb.add_sheet(sheet_name)
ws.write(n,m,my_data) # where n is the target row and m the column
```

in the end just save:

```
wb.save('workbook.xls')
```